# How to convert an string array into a character array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Suppose that we have an string array in Matlab like bellow:

```
   a='This is a book'
```

How can we convert the above string array into a character array by a function in Matlab like bellow?

```
    b={'T' 'h' 'i' 's' ' ' 'i' 's' ' ' 'a' ' ' 'b' 'o' 'o' 'k'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `a` is not a string array; it's a character array (which also used to be called a string, but starting from R2016b that term has a [different meaning](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html)). Your `b` is not a character array, it's a cell array that contains characters.

Anyway, to convert from `a` to `b`, use `num2cell`:

```
a = 'This is a book';
b = num2cell(a);
```

Comment: thanks for your precise information and simple answer :)

Comment: @Saeed_Mousazadeh Welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you really really want to convert string (introduced since R2016b) to char array, this is how you do.

```
s = "My String"; % Create a string with ""
c = char(s); % This is how you convert string to char. 
isstring(c)

ans =

logical

0

ischar(c)

ans =

logical

1
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :), but i'm using the version R2013a and so as you said your code is valid since version R2016b.